# Xamarin, Visual Studio 2017 (comunity), Main.axml warning "This project contains resources that were not compiled successfully"

Tags: xamarin

i'm in a research team that is in a middle of experiment frameworks for mobile and on the Xamarin part and i came around this warning that persists. 
I've already tried looking for answers around here and other developer forums but apparently almost nobody saw this warning.

I came around this question in here (StackOverflow question 49352946) and tried everything that was there as an answer but the problem dont go away.

So i was expecting somebody has had this problem and could get me some more tips 
I think it might be a problem with the setup of the environment (sdk, ndk or jdk) because its a very rare warning.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post code and log?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The problem that I have is that I don't get to the code part, all happens in the layout on the axml file. For example it doesn't let me add more than on icon or button or box from the toolbox

Comment: Understood. So, you are referring to xamarin.android? Can you post the axml?

Comment: Yes, this all happend when i was starting to understand how to work with xamarin and xaml. like i've said, it doesnt let me put more than 1 icon or box in the layout page.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>

This is the source of the axml file of the layout that doesnt work,

Comment: Try removing all semi colons from your markup.

Comment: I was looking to that, as you had said, but i realise that the semi colons only appear here in the coment, in the axml file its gone.
Maybe its because the coment section read it as a url and add them.